# Right mvc concept, little php code in view

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have one not understood point In MVC pattern. Please help understood.

for example we have table for cars in database, we want obtain and print results from table, but if results are not found (0 rows), in this case print: "We dont have results"

this is `models.php`

```
class modesl {

function getCars () {

    $res = $this->db->query("SELECT names FROM cars");
    if ($res->num_rows == 0) {
        return "We dont have results";
    }
    else {
        return $res;
    }

}

}
```

this is `views.php`

```
class views {

    function loadHTML ($resultFromCars) {
         require 'carspage.php';
    }

}
```

this is `carspage.php`

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

    if (is_object($resultFromCars)) {
        while ($row = $resultFromCars->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['names']."<br>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo  $resultFromCars;
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is `controllers.php`

```
class controllers {

    function generatePage () {  
        $model = new models();
        $resultFromCars = $model->getCars();


        $view = new views();
        $view->loadHTML($resultFromCars);
    }

}
```

This works, but as I know, many php code in view, (that is condition `if (is_object) { } else { }` ) is not right MVC. tell please for this concret case, what must be change in my architecture (lol), for obtain right MVC concept?

Comment: Seems ok to me, besides some fine tuning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have done a good job, just one small thing to improve. As the model is a wrapper for data only, so you should return only data (and no strings, containing error/exception messages). In the case there's no data to return, then return `FALSE`, as it's done in PHP.

```
class CarModel {

    function getCars () {

        $res = $this->db->query("SELECT names FROM cars");
        if ($res->num_rows == 0) {
            return FALSE; // if that happens, the function will stop execution here, so no "else" is needed
        }

        return $res;

    }

}
```

And in your view

```
<?php

    if ($resultFromCars === FALSE && !empty($resultFromCars)) {
        echo "We don't have results";
    }
    else { // now you know it's not FALSE, so it must be an object, no need to check whether it is one
        while ($row = $resultFromCars->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['names']."<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What I not understood, this is your update :) that is, how can be resultat empty? why needed check: `!empty($resultFromCars)` ?

Comment: Wasn't sure what sort of DB library you're using, but it's optional, if you're sure it can't be an empty array, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I like the answer provided by Havelock.

I would adjust this even further, by making sure your model already returns the data in an array format (or false, if nothing is found). Therefore, the logic for extracting data from resultset stays in the model, where it really should be.

Your view becomes even simpler then:

```
<?php

if (!empty($results)) {
  foreach ($results as $row) {
   echo $row['name'] . "<br />";
  }
} else {
    echo "Eh, Nothing found...";
}
```